# Python if statement

Tags: python

```
print("this program will calculate the area")

input("[Press any key to start]")

width = int(input("enter width"))
if width < 0:
    print ("please chose a number between 0-1000")
    width = int(input("enter width"))

if width > 1000000:
    print ("please chose a number between 0-1000")
    width = int(input("enter width"))

height = int(input("Enter Height"))

area = width*height

print("The area is:",area)
```

Is there a way i can condense the code below for example fit them together so i won't have to write just about the same line of code except the less then and greater then statement twice.

```
width = int(input("enter width"))
if width < 0:
    print ("please chose a number between 0-1000")
    width = int(input("enter width"))

if width > 1000000:
    print ("please chose a number between 0-1000")
    width = int(input("enter width"))
```

I have tried

```
width = int(input("enter width"))
if width < 0 and > 10000:
    print ("please chose a number between 0-1000")
    width = int(input("enter width"))
```

But i get no love.

I also don't want to type

```
width = int(input("enter width"))
```

statement twice if it can be helped.

Thanks
Ben

Comment: Nice work guys, Ty for your time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it. The most explicit is this:

```
if width < 0 or width > 10000:
```

but my favourite is this:

```
if not 0 <= width <= 10000:
```

Comment: Really you where all rite so thanks, but this one suited me best :)

Answer (score 3):

You need a loop.  Otherwise, the user can still enter an invalid value if they are persistent.  The while statement combines a loop with a conditional - it keeps looping until the condition is broken.

```
width = -1
while width < 0 or width > 10000:
    width = int(input("enter width as a positive integer < 10000"))
```

Your use of the if statement in the original question is syntactically incorrect:

```
if width < 0 and > 10000:
```

You want:

```
if not (0 < width < 1000):
    ask_for_new_input()
```

or, in a more explicit way:

```
if width < 0 or width > 1000:
    ask_for_new_input()
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to say

```
if width < 0 or width > 10000:
    print ("please chose a number between 0-1000")
    width = int(input("enter width"))
```

Comment: Nobody wants to say `width < 0 or > 10000`.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
if width < 0 and > 10000:
```

should read

```
if width < 0 or width > 10000:
```

Alternatively:

```
if not 0 <= width <= 10000:
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss variable width

```
if width < 0 or width> 10000:
```

Answer (score 0):

What if:

```
print("this program will calculate the area")

res = raw_input("[Press any key to start]")

def get_value(name):
    msg = "enter {0}".format(name)
    pMsg = "please choose a number between 0-1000"
    val = int(input(msg))
    while val not in xrange(1, 1001):
        print pMsg
        val = int(input(msg))
    return val


print("The area is: {0}".format(get_value('width') * get_value('height')))
```